# How to use Junit5 to receive the LocalDate value as params?

Tags: java, junit5

Last few days I learned the Junit5 in offical. And Recently I want to use it as my test instance,But I meet a difficulty.

I try to let LocalDate value as the params,But I have tried all of my knowledge to do it and all failed.

this is my code

```java
    @ParameterizedTest
@CsvSource({"2020-2-2,2010-2-3"})
    void t5_1(LocalDate a, LocalDate b) {
        final Duration between = Duration.between(a, b);
        System.out.println(between.toDays());
    }
    static Stream<Arguments>timeArrayProvider() {
        return Stream.of(
                Arguments.of((Object) new String[]{"2020-2-2","2010-2-3"})
        );
    }
```

If you know it ,Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you may need to provide an `ArgumentConverter` with a `@ConvertWith` annotation. See [this example](https://www.baeldung.com/parameterized-tests-junit-5#2-explicit-conversion) for reference.

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution that uses the Default Converter:

```
@ParameterizedTest
@CsvSource({"true, 3.14159265359, AUGUST, 2018, 2018-08-23T22:00:00"})
void testDefaultConverters(
    boolean b, double d, Summer s, Year y, LocalDateTime dt) { }

enum Summer {
    JUNE, JULY, AUGUST, SEPTEMBER;
}
```

If your dates don't come in ISO 8601, @JavaTimeConversionPattern helps you out:

```
@ParameterizedTest
@CsvSource({"true, 3.14159265359, AUGUST, 2018, 23.08.2018"})
void testDefaultConverters(
    boolean b, double d, Summer s, Year y,
    @JavaTimeConversionPattern("dd.MM.yyyy") LocalDate dt) { }
```

Kudos to Nicolai Parlog: https://nipafx.dev/junit-5-parameterized-tests/